# React Native high re-render time cost

Tags: react-native

I am currently developing an application in React Native but it works very slowly. The application shows a list of about 15 numbers that change approximately every 100ms. The problem is that the JS thread works at about 20-30 fps, which slows down the rest of the app.

I have recreated the problem in a sandbox project and the same thing happens.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay) {
      const tick = () => savedCallback.current();
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};


const Line = ({ item }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(item);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCurrent((c) => c + 1);
  }, 100);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{current}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}


const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Line key={item} item={item} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};


export default App;
```

Is there any way to re-render a component without it being so expensive for the JS thread? At the moment I am only developing for Android, so I have not tried how it works on iOS.

I'm using react-native@0.61.5

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things can do to improve your application performance. Since your application trying to show a list, use one of the list components such as [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) or [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) in React Native for bounded memory use & better performance. [Check out this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views) for more details.

1. Avoiding Unnecessary Renders Using PureComponent
2. Add `initialNumToRender` prop on your FlatList
   This defines how many items will be rendered for the first time.
3. Define the `key(keyExtractor)` prop on your Item Component
   This will avoid re-render dynamically added or removed items
4. Use `getItemLayout` to skip measurement of dynamic content.

Also, there is some prop called `maxToRenderPerBatch`, `windowSize` that you can use to increase the performance of the application.

Check [Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance) official documentation for more information.
Also, check this beautiful [article](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips) to improve the performance of FlatList.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Unfortunately, using FlatList almost does not increase the performance in this example. Although I will consider it for larger lists.

Comment: @PedroJavierNicolas you are right for small list ```FlatList`` performance increase may not be visible. But it is recommended to use the list component if you are trying to show a list.